# jQuery simulate click event on select option

Tags: jquery, select, click

I have a select menu that triggers an AJAX request once one of the options has been clicked. I need to trigger a click event on the relevant option from a link. So I have code similar to the below, and although it changes the value of the select, it doesn't simulate a click:

```js
$('#click').click(function(){
    var value = $(this).attr("rel");
    $('#select').val(value);
    return false;
});
```

```html
<select id="select" name="select">
    <option>Select...</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
    
<a href="#" rel="1" id="click">Click for option 1</a>
```

Answer (score 20):

Triggering a click event on the option will not work. Here is a snippet that does:

```
    $('#click').on('click', function(){
        var value = $(this).attr('rel'); //get the value
        value++; //increment value for the nth-child selector to work

        $('#select')
          .find('option:nth-child(' + value + ')')
          .prop('selected',true)
          .trigger('change'); //trigger a change instead of click

        return false;
    });
```

I have setup a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tg20kq5a/) showing the same.
This should work.

Instead of using a click you can trigger the change event and achieve the same effect.

Comment: IMO your answer is better as many select have an onchange function :)

Comment: I didn't realize that 'nth-child' starts at `1` *not `0` !* - https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/  : *"Because jQuery's implementation of :nth- selectors is strictly derived from the CSS specification, the value of n is "1-indexed", meaning that the counting starts at 1. "*  Nice pointer, thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    var value = $(this).attr("rel");
    $('#select')
        .val(value)
        .trigger('click');
    return false;
});
```

Merely setting the value of a `<select>` does not trigger the click event of that element; it must be called directly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That does make sense, but I have implemented your example above and it is still not triggering the AJAX call that is made when an option has been selected. Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of triggering a click event, trigger a change event.

Answer (score -2):

It's part of WooCommerce core, so I cannot post all of it. But here is a snippet although I am not too sure if it will tell you much...

```
.on( 'change', '.variations select', function( event ) {

    $variation_form = $(this).closest('form.variations_form');
    $variation_form.find('input[name=variation_id]').val('').change();

    $variation_form
        .trigger( 'woocommerce_variation_select_change' )
        .trigger( 'check_variations', [ '', false ] );

    $(this).blur();

    if( $().uniform && $.isFunction( $.uniform.update ) ) {
        $.uniform.update();
    }

} )
```