# How to preload <options> and <select> with Jquery-option-tree plugin

Tags: php, jquery, select, click

I am using Jquery-option-tree plugin on a standalone website not based on Wordpress as in example 7 on the demo page, except that I am not passing a .txt file but a PHP page is generating the array of < options > to be passed to the plugin.

http://kotowicz.net/jquery-option-tree/demo/demo.html

This perfectly works: so let's say that the user wants to select a category for a new product, the plugin suits the purpose generating a nice: " Food -> fruit -> apples " upon user clicks. (see demo page ex. 7)

What instead if a product already exists with its categories assigned? I want to show it to the user when he edit that product, preloading the tree.

I have the ids path coming from database, so it would just be a matter of having the plugin to run without the user interact, using the value I pass. I saw this question: [jQuery simulate click event on select option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549975/jquery-simulate-click-event-on-select-option)
and tried to simulate user' click with this (and other) methods with no luck.

```
 $('#select')
    .val(value)
    .trigger('click');
```

Here the call to the function:

```
$(function() {
                var options = {
                        empty_value: '',
                        set_value_on: 'each',
                        indexed: true,  // the data in tree is indexed by values (ids), not by labels
                        on_each_change: '/js/jquery-option-tree/get-subtree.php', // this file will be called with 'id' parameter, JSON data must be returned
                        choose: function(level) {
                            return 'Choose level ' + level;
                        },
                        loading_image: '/js/jquery-option-tree/ajax-load.gif',
                        show_multiple: 10, // if true - will set the size to show all options
                        choose: ''
                    };

                $.getJSON('/js/jquery-option-tree/get-subtree.php', function(tree) { // initialize the tree by loading the file first

                    $('input[name=parent_category_id]').optionTree(tree, options);
                });
            });
```

Here you can see the plugin:

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-option-tree/

Comment: not trying to figure out all your issues but triggering click on a select tag is not a normal event , normally you would trigger `change`. `click` is worthless since it occurs several times during the user selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that plugin, but looking at the examples there seems to be one that fits your need; **Example 6 - AJAX lazy loading & setting value on each level change**.

This would, in theory, just require some config options:

```
preselect: {'demo6': ['220','226']}, // array of default values - if on any level option value will be in this list, it will be selected
preselect_only_once: true, // prevent auto selecting whole branch when user maniputales one of branch levels
get_parent_value_if_empty: true,
attr: "id" // we'll use input id instead of name
```

If this doesn't fit you need though, you could initiate it from an event, like *change*, *keyup*, etc.

```
$(document).on('change', '#select', function() {
    $('#nextSelect').val($(this).val());
})

$(document).on('change', '#nextSelect', function() {
    $('#finalInput').val($(this).val());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right Mackan ! I saw that "preselect" option but I was initially unable to use it transferring the path from database to javascript, I ended up with my "newbie" solution to match the syntax:

```
preselect: {'parent_category_id': [0,'2','22']},
```

PHP

$category_path comes from DB query and is like "0,2,76,140,"

```
    $path = explode(',', $category_path);
    $preselect="";
    foreach ($path as $value) {
        $int = (int)$value;
        if ($int != 0) $preselect.= "'". $int ."',";
        else $preselect.= $int.","; // have to do this as ZERO in my case has to be without apostrophes '' 
    }
    $preselect = "{'parent_category_id':[".$preselect."]}"
```

JS

```
 var presel= <?php echo($preselect); ?>;
 var options = {
        preselect: (presel),
 }
```

Any suggestion for a better code ?
Thanks a lot !!